# Delete everything AFTER the cursor (or delete everything after the current word)

Tags: vim

I find myself in this situation quite often in vim:

```
response.status == 404
^
```

My cursor is on the `r` character and I want to delete everything after the current WORD. I can do `ElD` to move to the end of the word, shift the cursor, delete until EOL. Alternatively I could do something like `WDx` to move to the next WORD, delete the whole line, and delete the extra space.

Additionally it would be nice to keep my cursor in relatively the same position as I started (I guess I could use marks for that)

Are there any shortcuts that might make this easier (e.g. less capitals, less strokes)? I'm also just trying to not use `h`, `l`, and `x` as much. I could add something custom, but I'd prefer to use the native keybinds

Comment: You already got two three-key alternatives; I don't think it can get any better with built-ins. Only a custom motion would shorten this further.

Comment: Another 3 key alternative is `f<space>D`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically I use `WDD` for that purpose, which will avoid pressing a third key.

Obviously, you lose the relevant part of the deleted code, so you can't use this for cut&paste.

Comment: Nice! I actually like this a lot. Doesn't avoid the three presses, but doing a double press works for me

Comment: Ups... Looking again at this, what I really meant was `WDD`! I hope that's what you assumed. Should I update the answer?

Comment: Fixed. Feel free to remove this as the chosen answer if you no longer agree with it.

Comment: Legit! Simple, yet effective. Double tap is quick.

Answer (score 5):

#### Vim golfing

Now it is common practice in Vim to try and reduce keystrokes for certain tasks, commonly referred to as *golfing*. Often this practice uses the following general techniques:

- Use lesser used motions or commands. e.g. `ZZ`, `])`, `gi`
- Use an operator and motion instead of a count. `2dd` vs `dj`
- Using counts to do more at a time. e.g. `4j`
- Use repeatable motions. e.g. `fX` and use `,`/`;` to repeat the `f` motion
- Reuse patterns via `//`
- Take advantage of given text. This often fails with more generalized solutions.
- Use ex-commands with clever ranges. e.g. `v/./,//-j`
- Use marks, but especially use marks that are vim set for you. e.g `` '` ``, `'^`.

#### Premature optimization is the root of all evil

Now Vim golfing is a "good thing" as it typically helps the vimmer to find new motions or techniques, but it only so helpful in the average day-to-day workflow as golfing usually require a decent amount of forethought. One cannot worry about every single keystroke for every task all-day every day (aka premature optimization).

Instead focus on optimizing the common or lengthy tasks. Do this by creating a custom mapping or command to make such task quick and painless as possible and get on with your day.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you'd want this, but - if you do it, *this* use-case becomes easier, and uses only 'native' keybindings. So - you can add, for your desired `FileType`, this:

```
:setlocal iskeyword+=.
```

Then, you can use `elD` instead of `ElD`, (easier on the wrist).

But, frankly, if it bothers you enough to ask about it, it means it happens often enough that it should really be accessible from an even easier/shorter, *custom* key binding ;)